# Cocos2dx Memory consumption

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, cocos2d-x

I'm using coco2dx v2.2.6 and as per my scenario...
 - i have a scene which is calling itself again and again.
 - each time i load a different layer with differnet texture or sheets.
 - i load the assets in on-enter and remove them in on-exit.
 - each time texture and sheets get removed but memory usage doesnt get reset. say scene 1 was using 5 MB, scene 2 with 7 MB (2MB addition of last scene, because it was getting held somewhere)
 - a stage come when scene with live texture size > 15 MB, engine purges the cache and texture and it crashes.
 - basically memory in increasing constantly without lowering down even after removing the texture, cache, pool etc after each scene.

- sometime i need to play video as well on a particular layer, as i start them by tap or something, receives memory warning, and engine throw everything out of memory(sheets and texture) resulting crash by pressure.
- in short i need to retain min 20MB texture at a time without receiving memory warning. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: I'd use Xcode profiler to find a leak. Use CC_SAFE_RELEASE for releasing cocos2d-x objects, CC_SAFE_DELETE for other objects, CC_SAFE_FREE for simple arrays (like array of ints or strings). Find all "new" keywords in your code and make sure you release all of them.